# descending ordered Linked list shows does not show it in order

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

My polynomial linked list doesnt work for some inputs can someone tell me where i went wrong?

The following input doesnt work but

```
 insert(10, 1);
    insert(20, 2);
    insert(30, 3);
    insert(50, 5);
    insert(60, 6);
    insert(40, 4);
```

but this works

```
insert(60, 6);
    insert(20, 2);
    insert(50, 5);
    insert(40, 4);
    insert(10, 1);
    insert(30, 3);
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct Node
{
    int coeff;
    int pow;
    struct Node *next;
};
struct Node *head = NULL;
void insert(int coeff, int pow)
{
    struct Node *link = (struct Node *)(malloc(sizeof(struct Node)));
    link->coeff = coeff;
    link->pow = pow;
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        link->next = NULL;
        head = link;
    }
    else
    {
        if (pow > head->pow)
        {
            link->next = head;
            head = link;
        }
        else
        {
            struct Node *temp = head;
            while ((temp->pow > pow + 1) && (temp->next))
                temp = temp->next;
            link->next = temp->next;
            temp->next = link;
        }
    }
}
void print()
{
    struct Node *temp = head;
    while (temp->next)
    {
        printf("%dx^%d+", temp->coeff, temp->pow);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("%dx^%d=0", temp->coeff, temp->pow);
}
int main()
{
    insert(10, 1);
    insert(20, 2);
    insert(30, 3);
    insert(50, 5);
    insert(60, 6);
    insert(40, 4);
   

    print();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As always when dealing with things like lists, I recommend you take some time to sit down with a piece of paper and a pencil. Do all the operations on paper, drawing small boxes for the nodes in the list, and arrows for the links between the nodes. Erase and redraw the arrows as you do the operations on the list. Make sure that it all does what you want, then do it again using a clean paper to really make sure. *Then* you sit down at the computer to put it into code.

Comment: If you already got code, then use a debugger to step through the code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values. As you step through the code, again use paper and pencil to draw the operations performed by the code. That should hopefully make it easier to see when something goes wrong.

Comment: I thought about this method for a while and then implemented it

Comment: Please explain why sometimes you compare to `pow` and sometimes to `pow+1`.

Comment: Please explain what exactly you mean by "doesnt work". What are the symptoms?

Answer (score 1):

```
while ((temp->pow > pow + 1) && (temp->next))
    temp = temp->next;
```

Your iteration logic is faulty. I think you are trying to iterate temp to a position where the next element should be *link* (your new node). But to determine this position, your logic is wrong.

```
5 -> 3 -> 1
```

If you will try to insert 2 here, at **temp=head** - *5>(2+1) && temp->next* which is true. So you will end up inserting 2 after 5, which is incorrect.

I am avoiding spoon feeding you the solution. Please try to build on this. Also, it seems that the list ordering has got nothing to do *coeff*, you are only comparing on *pow*. In future you may want to abstract out the unnecessary details from the question.

Answer (score 0):

there are errors in your program, logical errors , which compiler does not show and neither it occurs during runtime. Let me tell you why your code does not works for first set. Take insert(10,1) and insert(20,2) .during first insert, your value will be stored in first node due to first if and during second insert pow value 2 will be compared with head.pow in second if and value stored in head.pow is 1 so second if will become true and your program will exit after doing your if statement and node will not be connected but instead your head will be updated to the new link which is not connected and this happens evertime when pow>head.pow that is in your first set of input .you need to correct your logic there. May be if you can share output for both set of inputs I'll be able to help you more but i say it's better if you try to correct your logic on your own. If you still want help then let me know.

Answer (score 0):

There you go fixed it for you

You have to compare to next power and add it to the list

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct Node
{
    int coeff;
    int pow;
    struct Node *next;
};
struct Node *head = NULL;
void insert(int coeff, int pow)
{
    struct Node *link = (struct Node *)(malloc(sizeof(struct Node)));
    link->coeff = coeff;
    link->pow = pow;
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        link->next = NULL;
        head = link;
    }
    else
    {
        if (pow > head->pow)
        {
            link->next = head;
            head = link;
        }
        else
        {
            struct Node *temp = head;
            while (temp->next && (temp->next->pow > pow))
                temp = temp->next;
            link->next = temp->next;
            temp->next = link;
        }
    }
}
void print()
{
    struct Node *temp = head;
    while (temp->next)
    {
        printf("%dx^%d+", temp->coeff, temp->pow);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("%dx^%d=0", temp->coeff, temp->pow);
}
int main()
{
    insert(70, 7);
    insert(50, 5);
    insert(20, 2);
    insert(10, 1);
    insert(80, 8);
    insert(60, 6);
    insert(30, 3);
    insert(40, 4);
    print();
    return 0;
}
```